# Low framerate with only map and minimap drawing (SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate

I'm working on a small "game" like project as a practice, and I've managed to get my framerate down to not even 3 FPS. While the only thing that is being drawn is screen filling tiles and a minimap.
Now I've found that the problem is with the minimap, without it caps at 60 FPS. But unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to find out what the real problem is with it...

My draw function:

```
void StateIngame::draw()
{
    m_gui.removeAllWidgets();
    m_window.setView(m_view);

    // Frame counter
    float ct = m_clock.restart().asSeconds();
    float fps = 1.f / ct;
    m_time = ct;

    char c[10];
    sprintf(c, "%f", fps);
    std::string fpsStr(c);
    sf::String str(fpsStr);

    auto fpsText = tgui::Label::create();
    fpsText->setText(str);
    fpsText->setTextSize(16);
    fpsText->setPosition(15, 15);
    m_gui.add(fpsText);

    //////////////
    // Draw map //
    //////////////
    int camOffsetX, camOffsetY;
    int tileSize = m_map.getTileSize();
    Tile tile;

    sf::IntRect bounds = m_camera.getTileBounds(tileSize);

    camOffsetX = m_camera.getTileOffset(tileSize).x;
    camOffsetY = m_camera.getTileOffset(tileSize).y;

    // Loop and draw each tile
    // x and y = counters, tileX and tileY is the coordinates of the tile being drawn
    for (int y = 0, tileY = bounds.top; y < bounds.height; y++, tileY++)
    {
        for (int x = 0, tileX = bounds.left; x < bounds.width; x++, tileX++)
        {
            try {
                // Normal view
                m_window.setView(m_view);
                tile = m_map.getTile(tileX, tileY);
                tile.render((x * tileSize) - camOffsetX, (y * tileSize) - camOffsetY, &m_window);
            } catch (const std::out_of_range& oor)
            {}
        }
    }


    bounds = sf::IntRect(bounds.left - (bounds.width * 2), bounds.top - (bounds.height * 2), bounds.width * 4, bounds.height * 4);

    for (int y = 0, tileY = bounds.top; y < bounds.height; y++, tileY++)
    {
        for (int x = 0, tileX = bounds.left; x < bounds.width; x++, tileX++)
        {
            try {
                // Mini map
                m_window.setView(m_minimap);
                tile = m_map.getTile(tileX, tileY);
                sf::RectangleShape miniTile(sf::Vector2f(4, 4));
                miniTile.setFillColor(tile.m_color);
                miniTile.setPosition((x * (tileSize / 4)), (y * (tileSize / 4)));
                m_window.draw(miniTile);
            } catch (const std::out_of_range& oor)
            {}
        }
    }

    // Gui
    m_window.setView(m_view);
    m_gui.draw();
}
```

The `Tile` class has a variable of type `sf::Color` which is set during map generating. This color is then used to draw the minimap instead of the 16x16 texture that is used for the map itself.

So when I leave out the minimap drawing, and only draw the map itself, it's more fluid than I could wish for...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what exactly is your problem?  That this is capped at 60fps?

Comment: It only runs at 3 fps, which is because of the minimap drawing loop. When I remove that, it runs at 60, which is fine.

Comment: Rather than using a view to draw the minimap, it will probably be faster and more flexible to render the minimap to a [RenderTexture](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php) and then draw that texture where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating the view completly new for every frame. Do this once on startup should be enought.

Comment: And then regenerate on movement of the camera? Wouldn't that have the same effect but then only when moving the camera?

Comment: While I didn't really understand how your answer would make this work, combining it with 0x5453's comment has resolved my problem.
I now generate a `sf::RenderTexture` with 1x1 pixel shapes on startup. The whole map, instead of with bounds is drawn to that texture. In my draw function only the portion of that texture that is needed is drawn.